# how to close a modal (bootstrap) and reload the page with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and angularJS and I don't know how to hide a modal and reload the page. I know I can reload with $route.reload() and hide it with $('#modalpolicy').modal('hide') but if I use both, the webpage doesn't show correctly (it's still black). How can I do it?

EDIT. At least I've decided to do a new query sooo I have the information up-to-date. on the page.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Does the page really need to be reloaded, or could a solution be to update the scope as needed in the hide event of the modal?

Comment: The question is a bit too broad.  Try adding some console logging in various places to help you figure out what's going on, and if you still haven't figured it out, edit the question to add enough information to let us help you.

Comment: Yes, because I need other information related by the information of that modal. So, either I reload the page or I do a get with this information. I prefer to reload because it's easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I reloaded it just calling the service again.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming to this question I recommend using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ for your bootstrap needs. Saves you from having to use jQuery in Angular which is rarely a good idea in the first place.

Comment: agreed. but then the answer should really be how it is done in angular world. I'm looking into this, will hopefully be able to post back